# Making Api Calls using different Access Token in PHP

Tags: php, token

I have sms queue table which temporary holds scheduled sms from different users, I run a cron job to check whether there is any message in the queue and send them if any. Each sms should consume sms token specifically for individual user. In my code below, the SDK was developed to send sms using only one token, how can I achieve sending sms using the individual token something like

`Sendsms1($user1_token,User1_sms);`
`Sendsms2($user2_token,User2_sms);` and so forth. I don't know if I am well understood.

```
$query_sch = "SELECT * FROM crbsms_queue
    LEFT JOIN crbusers ON crbsms_queue.user_id = crbusers.user_id"; 
    $sch_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sch); 

foreach($sch_result as $value)
      {
         $phone = $value['phones'];
         $sender = $value['sender']; 
         $message = $value['message']; 
         $user_id = $value['user_id'];
         $id = $value['id'];
         $token = $value["access_token"];
    
         $link_id = NULL;
         $correlator = "$id";
         $endpoint = 'https://example.com/delivery-url.php';
    
        $version = "v1"; //DONT change unless you are using a different version
        $instance = new BongaTech($token, $version);

        $list[] = new Sms($sender, $phone, $message, $correlator, null, $endpoint);
        
        
      if($list !== null){ 
    
      $row_chunks = array_chunk($list, 100);
      ////////here we have 100 messages on each chunk
        ///////Loop through the messages in side the chunk
        foreach ($row_chunks as $sms){
        
            $response = call_user_func_array(array($instance, "sendBatchSMS"), $sms);
            }// close chunk
        }//if not null
    }//close results mysqli

            $response = json_encode($response, true);
            $results = json_decode($response, true);
            print_r($response);
```

here is the sendbatch function

```
 /**
         * @param Sms ...$messages
         * @return mixed|string
         */
        public function sendBatchSMS(Sms ...$messages){
            $uri = "$this->version/send-sms";
            try {
                return (new SMSHandlerImpl($this->token, $uri, $messages))->process();
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working but it's sending messages multiple times per number depending with the number of tokens looped. What I want is one message per number using specific user token.

Comment: What actual problem occurs when you run this code? It looks like it would use a new instance of the API client for each message, passing the relevant token from the new row in the database. Therefore it seems to do what you're describing. If it's not working, then please provide us with specific information about how the code is behaving currently. Otherwise it's very hard to help you.

Comment: Yes this is working but it's sending messages multiple times per number depending with the number of tokens looped. What I want is one message per number using specific user token

Comment: That's because `foreach ($row_chunks as $sms){` runs once for every row in `$sch_result`, because you put it inside the outer foreach loop. So each time you process a new row, it sends _all_ the previous messages again. It's nothing to do with tokens, your loop logic is just wrong.

Comment: That's why I said the instance was designed to pass only one token. I need a way to consume more than 1 token with specific user message

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding what you mean by "consume more than 1 token with specific user message". According to your code, each message uses a single token. But did you get my point that you are re-sending all the messages every time you loop

Comment: I have a table users with userid and token I have another table queue with messages and userid, when I send a message, I want to am required to use sms units in the user account, this can be achieved by using the user token to query the units. In my implementation that I shared, the scripting is using sms units from all users at the same time instead of using sms units from the user account identified by the unique userid

Comment: I would have achieved this by sending 1 sms at ago but that is not a good approach, I want to send 100 sms at a time

Comment: See my answer below, this will stop the same message from being sent multiple times. This is likely to be why it appears to be using other units as well - because it's repeatedly sending messages which were targeted at other users. Try it, and see if it helps. They are still sent in batches of 100, but they aren't sent repeatedly.

Comment: No problem. P.S. You should probably add some logging to this part of the application, so that if units seem to be getting used up, and someone asks what is happening, then you can show them data about exactly which messages your application sent, when they were sent, and who to. This will provide an audit trail for debugging as well as for enquiries. It's generally good practice in a system like this, especially where every message sent is costing money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is nothing to do with tokens specifically, it's just that your loop logic is wrong.

`foreach ($row_chunks as $sms){` runs once for every row in `$sch_result`, because you put it inside the outer foreach loop. So each time you process a new row, it sends *all* the previous messages again, plus the new one.

To make that work you would put that loop after the first loop, so it waits till all the messages have been generated, and then sends all of them **once**.

However, because you want to use a different token for each message (so that each message is charged to a different account), you won't be able to send the messages in batches of 100. Instead each one must be sent separately, so that a new instance and token is used each time. Therefore, there's no need for chunking or separate loops to process the messages.

```
$query_sch = "SELECT * FROM crbsms_queue LEFT JOIN crbusers ON crbsms_queue.user_id = crbusers.user_id"; 
$sch_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sch);

foreach ($sch_result as $value)
{
     $phone = $value['phones'];
     $sender = $value['sender']; 
     $message = $value['message']; 
     $user_id = $value['user_id'];
     $id = $value['id'];
     $token = $value["access_token"];

     $link_id = NULL;
     $correlator = "$id";
     $endpoint = 'https://example.com/delivery-url.php';

    $version = "v1"; //DONT change unless you are using a different version
    $instance = new BongaTech($token, $version);
    $sms = new Sms($sender, $phone, $message, $correlator, null, $endpoint);
    $instance->sendBatchSMS($sms);
}
```

Comment: This has stopped the repetition but all sms are using one token throughout

Comment: Ah...sorry that's because it just uses the final value of $instance every time, since the loop has ended. I didn't spot that (and neither did you, presumably). You need a more sophisticated list structure so you can hold both the SMS and the related instance. Let me update it.

Comment: Ok updated it. But just so I'm sure it will really work as intended, can you please update your question to show the code for the sendBatchSMS function, please? Because I'm not quite convinced this is correct yet, and I can't be certain without seeing that code. Don't try it yet please, till I've seen that code.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, so the problem is that the sendBatchSMS function will use the same token to send all the messages in the chunk. Unless you can change how the `SMSHandlerImpl` class works (and ultimately it may be a limitation of the SMS gateway, potentially), then there is no way around that, you would have to send each message individually instead, rather than using batches. Your situation is probably unusual because you're trying to charge each message to a different account, whereas most bulk SMS sending is based on the assumption that a single sender pays in bulk for all the messages.

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: instance in
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: sms in 
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in <b>

Comment: Yes, well, I did tell you not to try it yet!

Comment: Try the version I've just updated to now. It will only send one message per batch, but it should ensure the correct token is used each time.

Comment: its displaying a blank page

Comment: I updated a couple of times. Are you using the most recent version? Anyway, a blank page can indicate an error, if you don't have error reporting switched on. If you don't have error reporting switched on, then ensure you've got error logging switched on instead, and then re-run and check the log file for exceptions. (Alternatively a blank page can simply indicate that you didn't generate any output. I don't know what output you're expecting, since there's no code shown which would generate any. As I said before, you should add some logging anyway to show what messages were sent).

Comment: Unless `$value["access_token"];` is the same in every row of your SQL results, then I can't see how that would really be possible.

Comment: Great, that's good to hear. Did you have to change anything compared to the code I wrote? If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as accepted and/or add an upvote - thanks :-)

Comment: How can get a response of this

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. Can you be more specific?

Comment: for example $response = call_user_func_array(array($instance, "sendBatchSMS"), $sms);  would return a status (Success/failed) response which I could decode and save the value in the db 
e.g $results = json_decode($response);
foreach($results as $result){

}

Comment: You can just do the same kind of thing with the call to sendBatchSMS as it's written now. It's calling exactly the same function, just with different syntax. So the return value will be exactly the same as well. e.g. `$response = $instance->sendBatchSMS($sms);`. And then do whatever you want with that `$response` variable.

Comment: sure it i got you